# Pass posted data to a teardown function

Tags: python, request, flask, paypal-ipn, python-2.6

I receive posted data and immediately return an empty `200 OK` response. After that I will process the received data. I'm considering how to do it with a `teardown` function but I didn't find how to pass it the received data:

```
@app.route('/f', methods = ['POST'])
def f():

    data = request.stream.read()
    return ''

@app.teardown_request
def teardwon_request(exception=None):

    # How to use posted data here?
```

Flask version is 0.10.1

I'm trying to implement a Paypal IPN listener

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/#overview

Notice that the listener's HTTP 200 response happens before the listener's IPN message.

Comment: Why would you do it that way? What advantage do you hope to gain from processing the request in the teardown?

Comment: I need to post the processing result to the caller. But the caller requires that first a `200 OK` response be sent and only then my post be sent in a different request.

Comment: Sorry, what? That doesn't scan. What does 'my post' mean in this context? The `200 OK` won't reach the caller until the `teardown_request` handler has completed, btw.

Comment: Note that `teardown_request` is meant for clean-up handlers only, to release resources allocated when a context started. They are not meant to handle anything to do with the request itself.

Comment: I was misinterpreting the `teardown_request`. I thought it would create another request object. If the `200 OK` will only be sent after the `teardown` then it will not work.

Comment: The HTTP model does not allow you to send two responses. You only get to have *one* response. You didn't give us any (understandable) details about what exactly you are trying to achieve here, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I updated the question with what I'm trying.

Comment: The HTTP 200 response and the POST request are separate. You first send the response, then send a POST request.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: The IPN request you send to paypal can also be sent before your 200 response completes. You just need to send an outgoing HTTP request.

Comment: Here's a Flask implementation: https://gist.github.com/doobeh/1869698

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things; just send a request from your Flask server in the request handler. Paypal IPN notifications just require a empty 200 response, Paypal does *not* mandate that you send the 200 OK *before* you can send the HTTP request to their servers.

The overview page is indeed confusing, but the PHP code posted won't close the request until the Paypal IPN post back to their server has completed either.

If this *was* a hard requirement (making this a terrible design), you'd have to handle the request back to Paypal asynchronously. You can do this with a separate thread, for example, using a queue, push in the data you received from the IPN, and have a separate thread poll the queue and communicate to Paypal from that thread. Or you could use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to simplify the job (push a task out to be handled asynchronously). Either way, this would let you close the incoming request early.

Comment: I will try that but that is not what I understand from that overview page

Comment: Indeed it works to just post the IPN message before closing the request. The 3 or 4 Paypal APIs I have used have very confusing documentation and were a struggle to implement. I only understood them after repeatedly testing.